# Convert String in Dictionary List

Tags: python, dictionary

I am new to python. I code below however I am hitting exception.

Input

```
studId=ValueA,studName=valueB;studId=ValueC,studName=ValueD
```

Output if list

```
[{'name':'ValueA','value':'valueB'},{'name':'ValueC','value':'valueD'}]
```

Output

```
ValueA
```

My code

```
str = "studId=ValueA,studName=valueB;studId=ValueC,studName=ValueD"

stud_list = dict(item.split("=") item.split(",") for item in str.split(";"))

for stud in stud_list :
  print(stud['studName'])
```

exception

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update the structure while loading the data

```
string = "studId=ValueA,studName=valueB;studId=ValueC,studName=ValueD"

stud_list = [dict(it.split("=") for it in item.split(",")) for item in string.split(";")]

for stud in stud_list :
  print(stud['studName'])
```

Comment: can i know have you ever tried using jinja2 as well. thanks it works. Just to confirm the logic it is using double loop correct?

Comment: no I didn't use jinja2.

Comment: First the outer loop will split the content at ";" and later for each data second for loop will execute.

Comment: i like to ask something, we need use only approach split semicolon followed by comma followed by equals. is there other approach u suggest

Comment: can we use single line in for rather than having seperate variable stud_list. I tried this was working "for stud in [dict(it.split("=") for it in item.split(",")) for item in str.split(";")] :"

Comment: Yes you can use, just make sure of parenthesis to get expected output.

Comment: I like to ask last question, why did you use different variable. I tried use same variable it was working "[dict(str.split("=") for str in str.split(",")) for str in str.split(";")]" Is there any reasons to use different variable?

Comment: It will work with same variable also, but it will be difficult to analyze the code later if you get any bugs.

Answer (score 0):

While I also enjoy comprehensions, more readably, one could:

```
inStr = "studId=ValueA,studName=valueB;studId=ValueC,studName=ValueD"

dict_list = []

for d in inStr.split(';'):
  dict_list.append({})
  for pair in d.split(','):
    k, v = pair.split('=')
    dict_list[-1][k] = v

print(dict_list)
```